# Почему после перезагрузки ноутбука на системном диске освобождается 20-30 гб и все начинает лагать?

Tags: ноутбук, пк

Все нормально, ноутбук, после перезагрузки с системного диска освобожается 20-30 гб места и все начинает лагать, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вирус, возможно? Проверяли?

Comment: Ну как минимум можно взять какую-нибудь программку для анализа занятого места (вроде WinDirStat или аналог) и поискать, кто конкретно занимает эти 20-30 Гб

Comment: Освобождается или пропадает? Это противоположные вещи.

Comment: Ось какая: винда, линукс? / "Освобождается" - может, файл подкачки удаляется, может, папка Temp удаляется. / "Начинает лагать" - как долго лагает? Так-то при старте оси запускается множество программ и сервисов. Docker, например, долго стартует. В Винде в Task Manager (Диспетчер задач) на вкладке Startup можно посмотреть, какие программы сильно влияют на старт.

Comment: Винда 10 про, просто после перезапуска ноута на системном диске освободилось 20 Гб места и теперь все лагает, производительность упала по идее,